# Change VNC password without losing the session

Tags: redhat, command-line-interface, vnc

I have a VNC session to my server(linux), but now i need to change their password, however, i cannot lose that session.

If I use this command:

```
vncpasswd [passwd-file]
```

Does anyone know if I will lose the session or if the VNC service will restart?

Thanks

Comment: Which VNC software? Can you test it on another pc/server?

Comment: vncserver and i only access via my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Changing of you password will not impact your current connection. `vncpasswd` command writes a passwd file which is read when you make new connection, so it will not impact current connections.